# Odata Validation

Tags: json, validation, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Odata URI, and I want to validate responses against metadata.I tried Odata validation tool, but I am  not clear whether it is validating against metadata or just it is validating responses against set of OASIS specification rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can use olingo odata library to validate the responses.
Olingo has API which takes the response body and validates against EDM and returns ODataFeed object.

EntityProvider.readFeed(contentType, entitySet, content, properties);